# Getting Fortran Runtime error : Index '1281' of dimension 1 of array 'c%particle_ad' above upper bound of 1280

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have this code and It does heavy calculations and I need to use open-mp library to get it done fast . This is my code :

```
    SUBROUTINE init_random_seed()

    implicit none
    INTEGER :: i, n, clock
    INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: seed
    CALL RANDOM_SEED(size = n)
    ALLOCATE(seed(n))
    CALL SYSTEM_CLOCK(COUNT=clock)
    seed = clock + 37 * (/ (i - 1, i = 1, n) /)
    CALL RANDOM_SEED(PUT = seed)
    DEALLOCATE(seed)

END SUBROUTINE

  !end module

Program Activ_mater
USE OMP_LIB
Implicit none
 Integer,parameter :: time=1000000000, L=128,  N = L**2*2
 Integer,parameter:: n_thread = 8
 Real(8),parameter :: pi = 3.14159265359
 Real(8),parameter :: v0 = 0.50, alpha = 1.0/36.0
 real(8)START,END_1 ,eta
type block_p
    Integer :: partical_N
    Integer :: particle_ad(10*L)
end type

Type(block_p) ,pointer,dimension(:,:)    :: C

 Real(8),allocatable :: x(:), y(:) , phi,angle_new(:),angle(:)
 Real(8) :: sum_a, sum_b,x_in, y_in, x_out, y_out, avrage_t, r,ra,eta1(5)
 Integer :: i,j,t,n_p,I_b,J_b,b_l,neighbor_i(9),neighbor_j(9),A,n_p_b,ne = 1,stateta=0,ot=0,op=175
character(len=10)::name1
call omp_set_num_threads(n_thread)
call init_random_seed()


eta1=(/2.100,2.116,2.120,2.126,2.128/)           ! The value of ETA
allocate(x(2*n), y(2*n) , phi,angle_new(2*N),angle(2*N))
allocate(C(2*L,2*L))
C(:,:)%partical_N=0

do i =1,N
    call random_number(ra)
    x(i)=ra*L
    I_b = int(x(i))+1
    call random_number(ra)
    y(i)=ra*L
    J_b = int(y(i))+1
     call random_number(ra)
     angle(i)=ra*2.0*pi
     C(I_b,J_b)%partical_N = C(I_b,J_b)%partical_N + 1      !Number of particle in block C(I_b,J_b)
     C(I_b,J_b)%particle_ad( C(I_b,J_b)%partical_N ) = i    ! The particle number in block C(I_b,J_b)
end do
             ! loop for eta
 eta= 0.0
 write(name1,'(f5.3)')eta
  open(unit=10, file='Hysteresis,'//trim(name1)//'.dat')
     !=====================explanation of system====================================
     print*,'==========================================================================='
     print*, 'eta = ', etA ,'         ',' alpha = ',alpha
     print*,'L=',L ,'         ', 'Particle Number=', N,'         ','Density=', N/L**2
     print*,'==========================================================================='
     !==============================================================================
START = omp_get_wtime()
do t =1,time
    if (ot == 300000 )then
        stateta = 0
        ot = 0
        op = op + 1
    end if
if (stateta == 0 )then
 eta = eta + ((1.0/3.0) * (10E-6))
 endif
 if (int(eta * 100) == op) then
    stateta = 1
 end if
 angle_new(:)=0
!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(PRIVATE) SHARED(x,y,angle,angle_new,c) firstprivate(eta)
 !$OMP DO schedule(runtime)
    do i =1, N
    sum_a=0; sum_b=0;n_p=0
     I_b = int(x(i))+1;  J_b = int(y(i))+1           ! The block of particle i
     ! Now I should find nine neighbor of particle i-----------------------------------------------
     neighbor_i=(/I_b+1, I_b,   I_b-1, I_b,   I_b+1, I_b-1, I_b-1, I_b+1, I_b/)
     neighbor_j=(/J_b,   J_b+1, J_b,   J_b-1, J_b+1, J_b+1, J_b-1, J_b-1, J_b/)
     do b_l = 1, 9
        I_b = neighbor_i(b_l) ; J_b=neighbor_j(b_l)
        if (I_b >L )I_b=1
        if (I_b <1 )I_b=L
        if (J_b >L )J_b=1
        if (J_b <1 )J_b=L
        !neighbor_i(b_l)=I_b; neighbor_j(b_l)=J_b
         A = C( I_b, J_b )%partical_N ! number of particle in block C( neighbor_i(b_l), neighbor_j(b_l) )
     !=============================================================================================
        do n_p_b =1, A

          j =  C( I_b, J_b)%particle_ad(n_p_b) !particle j in the block C

            if (i /= j )then
                X_in = abs(max(x(i),x(j)) - min(x(i),x(j)));
                Y_in = abs(max(y(i),y(j)) - min(y(i),y(j)));
                X_out =L-X_in
                Y_out =L-Y_in
                r = sqrt(min(X_in,X_out)**2 + min(Y_in,Y_out)**2)
            else
                r=0.0
            end if

                  if ( r < 1 )then
            if ( j <= i )then
                sum_A = sum_A + sin(angle(j));
                sum_B = sum_B + cos(angle(j));
            else
                sum_A = sum_A + alpha*sin(angle(j));
                sum_B = sum_B + alpha*cos(angle(j));
            endif
            n_p   = n_p + 1;
          endif
        enddo
        enddo
        sum_A = sum_A/n_p; sum_B = sum_B/n_p
!if (int(sum_A*1e10) ==0 .and. int(sum_B*1e10) ==0 )print*,'zerrooo'
        avrage_t=atan2(sum_A,sum_B);
        if (avrage_t<0.0) then
            avrage_t=avrage_t+2.0*pi;
        endif

         call random_number(ra)
        angle_new(i)=avrage_t+eta*(ra-0.50)

        if( angle_new(i)>=2*pi) angle_new(i)= angle_new(i)-2*pi
        if( angle_new(i)<0) angle_new(i)= 2*pi+angle_new(i)

    end do
     !$OMP END DO
       !$OMP END PARALLEL
    angle = angle_new
      C(:,:)%partical_N=0
     ! phi=0.0
        do i=1, N

            x(i) = x(i) + v0*sin(angle(i));
            if (x(i)<1) x(i)=L+x(i)
            if (x(i)>L)   x(i)=x(i)-L
            I_b = int(x(i))+1

            y(i) = y(i)+ v0*cos(angle(i));
            if (y(i)<1) y(i)=L+y(i)
            if (y(i)>L)   y(i)=y(i)-L
            J_b = int(y(i))+1
            C(I_b,J_b)%partical_N = C(I_b,J_b)%partical_N + 1
            C(I_b,J_b)%particle_ad( C(I_b,J_b)%partical_N ) = i
        end do
        if (stateta == 1 )then
             phi=  sqrt((sum(sin(angle))**2+sum(cos(angle))**2))/N;
             ot = ot + 1
        end if





    write(10,*)phi
        if (mod(t,10)==0)then
          !  ave4_phi=sum(phi**4)/t;
           ! ave2_phi =sum(phi**2)/t;
        !print* ,ave4_phi,ave2_phi
            print*,'Time=',t,' ==== Eta : ',eta,"Ot : " , ot
        end if

end do
END_1 = omp_get_wtime()
print*,'Run Time = ',end_1-start
 End Program
```

As you can see , there is a parameter "L" that defines number of particles . When "L" is lower , like 64 or 32 it works fine but when I increase it , I get the error .

Also without omplib it looks like it works fine in any L size but when I use it and compile it with `-g -fcheck=all` , I get this error :

```
At line 155 of file hyster.f90 Fortran runtime error: Index '1281' of dimension 1 of array 'c%particle_ad' above upper bound of 1280
```

I would be grateful if you help me .
Thank you all .

Comment: Without knowing more about your problem I suspect it will be very difficult to answer this. Is there a good reason why the particle_ad member of the dervied type has an upper bound of 10*L? It is far from obvious from the code,

Comment: Also please indent your code consistently, it probably only takes a couple of key strokes in your editor, note real( 8 ) is not portable, may not compile, and might not do what you expect (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter), and also your constants are single precision which may be losing your accuracy.

Comment: In your first `do i=1,N` block, consider what happens in the (unlikely) case where `random_number(ra)` returns `0` every time; `C(1,1)` will have `N=2*L**2` particles added, but only has space for `10*L` particles.